# How to vectorize nested loops in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, vectorization

I want to vectorize this operation:

```
for (row1 in 1:nrow(full_df)) {
  for (row2 in 1:nrow(icd10_codes)){
    if (any(full_df[row1, "coding_19"] %in% icd10_codes[row2, "present_icd10"])){
      full_df[row1, "code_count"] <- full_df[row1, "code_count"]+1
    }
  }
}
```

full_df is this:

```
full_df <- data.frame(
           coding_19=I(list(c("H353"), c("B20","B21", "B22", "B23","B24","Z21", "F024","O987"), c("G30","F00"), c("E780")))
)
full_df$code_count <- 0
```

`icd10_codes` looks like this. eid is the id of the person, and `present_icd10` are the codes associated to that person.

If you want you can just copy and paste:

```
data.frame(
    eid=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
    present_icd10=I(list(c("G30", "F00"), c("B20"), c("E780"), c("H401", "H409"), c("H353"), c("E780")))
    )
```

notice that `present_icd10` and `coding_19` are vectors of n dimensions.

I want to count the times where at least one element in `full_df$coding_19` (rowise) is present in each person (`present_icd10`)

The expected output should be:

```
coding_19                                              code_count
"H353"                                                     1
"B20", "B21", "B22", "B23", "B24", "Z21", "F024", "O987"   1
"G30", "F00"                                               1
"E780"                                                     2
```

Meaning that there is 1 person with code H353, 1 person with code B20, 1 person with either G30 or F00 (in this case both), and 2 persons with code E780.

I tried using this:

```
full_df <- full_df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(code_count = code_count + as.integer(any(coding_19 %in% icd10_codes$present_icd10)))
```

But I think this would only work if I had a single loop, not nested loops.

Comment: It would help immensely if you could provide unambiguous, representative data samples for both frames. Additionally, please make sure that there are some matches in the samples. The preferred method (esp since it looks like you have list-columns) is to use `dput(head(x))`. Thanks!

Comment: I feel like it would be helpful if you would provide an example of what the desired output would look like. I have trouble wrapping my head around what the nested for loops would result in.

Comment: I just edited adding the dataframes to copy and paste and also provided an output.

Comment: @Phil the reason I have a second for loop is because I don't want to count a person twice, if this person has more than one hit for each row in full_df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hackish, but it gets to your desired output:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

full_df <- full_df |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  mutate(id_row = row_number()) |> 
  unnest(coding_19)
icd10_codes <- icd10_codes |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  unnest(present_icd10)
```

For the above, the use of `unnest()` separates each of the codes into separate lines, and we'll rely on the id variables (which I created for `full_df`) to keep track as to which codes belong with which when wrapping up.

```
full_df |> 
  left_join(icd10_codes, by = join_by(coding_19 == present_icd10)) |> # Merge the two data frames together, using the codes as the key
  group_by(id_row) |> # For each id_row...
  fill(eid) |> # ... replace NAs with the eid
  group_by(id_row, eid) |> # And for each combination of id_row and eid
  summarize(coding_19 = paste(coding_19, collapse = ", ")) |> # ... collapse the codes back.
  ungroup() |> # And remove the grouping
  count(coding_19, name = "code_count") # And count the number of occurrences by `coding_19`.

# A tibble: 4 × 2
  coding_19                           code_count
  <chr>                                    <int>
1 B20, B21, B22, B23, B24, Z21, F024, O987     1
2 E780                                         2
3 G30, F00                                     1
4 H353                                         1
```

This would need to be tested to a larger dataset. There may be a lapse in logic in there.

---

EDIT:

With this data:

```
ex_icd10_codes <- data.frame(eid=1:7, 
                             present_icd10=I(list(c("G30", "F00"), "B20", "E780", c("H401", "H409"), "H353", "E780", "B20"))) 

full_df <- data.frame(
  coding_19=I(list("H353", c("B20","B21", "B22", "B23","B24","Z21", "F024","O987"), c("G30","F00"), "E780"))
)
```

We could do:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)

ex_icd10_codes <- ex_icd10_codes |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  unnest(present_icd10)

full_df |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  mutate(id_row = row_number(),
         coding_19 = map_chr(coding_19, ~ paste(.x, collapse = ", "))) |> # Collapse the codes into one string per row
  fuzzy_left_join(ex_icd10_codes, by = c("coding_19" = "present_icd10"), match_fun = str_detect) |> # Merge the two data frames together, using the codes as the key, if the code in ex_icd10_codes is in full_df
  distinct(eid, .keep_all = TRUE) |> # Remove duplicates
  count(coding_19, name = "code_count") # And count the number of occurrences by `coding_19`.

# A tibble: 4 × 2
  coding_19                                code_count
  <chr>                                         <int>
1 B20, B21, B22, B23, B24, Z21, F024, O987          2
2 E780                                              2
3 G30, F00                                          1
4 H353                                              1
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please just add some brief explanation on what you did?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem to be working for my larger dataset (the groupings of the codes don't come back together), but I will keep the checkmark since it worked for the one I requested here.

Comment: If you include the case(s) for which it fails, I can take a look.

Comment: For example if 2 people have "B20" the code breaks. Try with: ex_icd10_codes <- data.frame(
  eid=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
  present_icd10=I(list(c("G30", "F00"), c("B20"), c("E780"), c("H401", "H409"), c("H353"), c("E780"), c("B20")))
). The error is in filling the eid the way you do.

Comment: @Caterina See edit above to see if that now captures desired behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Based limited samples:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

full_df %>%  
  mutate(code_count = map_dbl(coding_19, ~ sum(unlist(pull(icd10_codes, present_icd10)) %in% .x)))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  coding_19 code_count
  <list>         <dbl>
1 <chr [1]>          1
2 <chr [8]>          0
3 <chr [2]>          1
4 <chr [1]>          2
```

Comment: `icd10_codes$present_icd10` is a list-column, not a string, this is masked with your wrapping `unlist(.)`. Is there a reason you are splitting it as well? Also, it is a nice courtesy when answers are specific about packages they are actually introducing, here it's `purrr` and `stringr`. The assumption of `tidyverse` is not perfectly safe, even though I know many beginner courses tend to rely on them.

Comment: the last row should be 2 not 1, since 2 people have this code (E780).

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the suggestions - updated. I initially thought that it was a string column, hence `str_split` for ", ".

Comment: @Caterina Updated, swapped places between `%in%`

Comment: Use R's built-in help for that: [`?pull`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pull.html) and [`?unlist`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/unlist.html).

Comment: All right. But unfortunately I'm getting a count of zero for those who are lists of string instead of strings. I have edited the question, putting "G30", "F00" instead of "G30" in icd10_codes dataframe.